# Trouble while installing truffle-contract module

Tags: truffle

When I run the command sudo npm install truffle-contract it gives me this error:

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone -q https://github.com/debris/bignumber.js.git /home/ubuntu/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-777489e7
npm ERR! /home/ubuntu/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-777489e7/.git: Permission denied
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2017-12-26T05_11_27_119Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. sudo apt-get update
2. update the nvm
3. update npm
4. update node
5. Use a different OS and start over.